# Using index information to generate cross references

Tags: cross-referencing, indexing, marginpar

The idea is to use the index information to automatically generate cross references. If an index entry refers to more than 1 page (e.g., "Smith, John  5, 9"), then the index entry along with the other page numbers should show up in the margin at the place where I make the index entry (*i.e.*, following the above example, on page 5 in the margin appears "Smith, John  9").

Is it possible to change the `showidx` package accordingly?

In addition, the solution should be compatible with `hyperref` and the fact that I'm using `twosided` but the bigger margin is always on the right (I'm using `tufte-latex`).

Thanks for any hints.

And here my try of an MWE (not sure whether that helps):

```
%\documentclass[twoside]{tufte-book}
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{makeidx,showidx,lipsum}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
John Smith\index{Smith, John}
\lipsum
John Smith\index{Smith, John}
\lipsum
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks interesting. Can you post a MWE?

Comment: added MWE, maybe it needs just a small tweak of showidx to give the page numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ["small tweak"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124109/using-index-information-to-generate-cross-references#comment278231_124109) is quite an understatement. After the usual processing of the `.idx` file by makeindex, the relation of the raw data inside `\index` (LaTeX file) or `\indexentry` (`.idx` file) to the formatted index entry in the `.ind` file gets lost. Example:

```
\index{foobar}         ⇒ \item foobar, ...
\index{foo@foobar}     ⇒ \item foobar, ...          (sort spec.
\index{foobar|(}       ⇒ \item foobar, ...          (range spec.)
\index{foobar|textbf}  ⇒ \item foobar, \textbf{1}   (encap feature)
\index{"f"o"o"b"a"r}   ⇒ \item foobar, ...          (quote char)
\index{foo!bar}        ⇒ \item foo ...\subitem bar  (level char)
\index{fooX@foo!barY@b"ar|(emph}
                        ⇒ \item foo ...\subitem bar  (sort + level + quote + range + encap)
```

From the generated index file, the exact form of `\index` can only be guessed
(e.g. `\index{foobar}` and `\index{foo!bar}`. The sort, range, encap specifications are gone. Thus the result from the generated index file would be a mapping from such keys to the page list, e.g.:

```
foobar  ⇒ 1, \textbf{2}, 3
foo!bar ⇒ 3--7, 10
```

The following package `indexpagelist` defines a style file `indexpagelist.ist` for makeindex that generates such a mapping.

Back at the LaTeX level, we need to strip the sort, range and encap specifications from the string, that is given to `\index`.

To reduce the level of complexity and to save some time, I have not implemented the support for quote and escape chars. Also the `actual`, `level`, and `encap` chars are only supported with their default values (`@`, `!`, `|`).

```
%%% indexpagelist.sty %%%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{indexpagelist}[2013/07/16 v0.1 Index page list for showidx] 
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{indexpagelist.ist}
preamble ""
postamble ""
setpage_prefix ""
group_skip ""
headings_flag 0
symhead_negative ""
numhead_negative ""
item_0 "\\iplItemA{"
item_1 "\\iplItemB{"
item_2 "\\iplItemC{"
item_01 "\\iplItemB{"
item_x1 "}\n\\iplItemB{"
item_12 "\\iplItemC{"
item_x2 "}\n\\iplItemC{"
delim_0 "}\n\\iplPageList{"
delim_1 "}\n\\iplPageList{"
delim_2 "}\n\\iplPageList{"
delim_n "\\iplMultiPage, "
delim_r "\\iplMultiPage--"
delim_t "}\n"
line_max 1000
\end{filecontents*}
\immediate\write18{%
  makeindex %
  -s indexpagelist.ist %
  -t \jobname-ipl.ilg %
  -o \jobname.ipl %
  \jobname.idx%
}
\immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname}% for convenience

\newcommand*{\iplItemA}[1]{%
  \def\iplCurrentItemA{#1}%
  \@onelevel@sanitize\iplCurrentItemA
  \let\iplCurrent\iplCurrentItemA
}
\newcommand*{\iplItemB}[1]{%
  \def\iplCurrentItemB{#1}%
  \@onelevel@sanitize\iplCurrentItemB
  \edef\iplCurrent{\iplCurrentItemA!\iplCurrentItemB}%
}
\newcommand*{\iplItemC}[1]{%
  \def\iplCurrentItemC{#1}%
  \@onelevel@sanitize\iplCurrentItemC
  \edef\iplCurrent{\iplCurrentItemA!\iplCurrentItemB!\iplCurrentItemC}%
}
\newcommand*{\iplPageList}[1]{%
  \expandafter\@ipl@PageList#1\iplMultiPage\@nil
}
\newcommand*{\iplMultiPage}{}
\def\@ipl@PageList#1\iplMultiPage#2\@nil{%
  \def\@ipl@Temp{#2}%
  \ifx\@ipl@Temp\@empty
  \else
    \expandafter\protected@xdef\csname ipl@\iplCurrent\endcsname{#1#2}%
  \fi
}
\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.ipl}{}{}

\newcommand*{\iplGetPageList}[1]{%
  \def\@ipl@Temp{#1}%
  \@onelevel@sanitize\@ipl@Temp
  \let\@ipl@Key\@empty
  \expandafter\@ipl@GetPageList@Encap\@ipl@Temp|\@nil
  \@ifundefined{ipl@\@ipl@Key}{}{%
    , \@nameuse{ipl@\@ipl@Key}%   
  }%
}   
\def\@ipl@GetPageList@Encap#1|#2\@nil{%
  \let\@ipl@Key\@empty
  \@ipl@GetPageList@Level#1!\@nil
}
\def\@ipl@Temp#1{%
  \def\@ipl@GetPageList@Level##1!##2\@nil{%
    \@ipl@GetPageList@Sort##1#1\@nil
    \def\@ipl@Temp{##2}%
    \ifx\@ipl@Temp\@empty
    \else
      \@ipl@GetPageList@Level##2\@nil
    \fi
  }%   
  \def\@ipl@GetPageList@Sort##1#1##2\@nil{%
    \def\@ipl@Temp{##2}%
    \edef\@ipl@Key{%
      \ifx\@ipl@Key\@empty
      \else
        \@ipl@Key!%
      \fi
      \ifx\@ipl@Temp\@empty
        ##1%
      \else 
        \@ipl@RemoveSortChar##2\@nil
      \fi
    }%   
  }%     
  \def\@ipl@RemoveSortChar##1#1\@nil{##1}%
}
\expandafter\@ipl@Temp\string @
% remaining "small tweak" for package showidx
\newcommand*{\iplPatchShowidx}{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{showidx}{%  
    \@ifdefinable{\saved@showidx}{%
      \let\saved@showidx\@showidx  
      \renewcommand*{\@showidx}[1]{%
        \saved@showidx{##1\iplGetPageList{##1}}%
      }%
    }%  
    \global\let\iplPatchShowidx\relax
  }{}%
}
\iplPatchShowidx
\AtBeginDocument{\iplPatchShowidx}
\endinput
```

Then the "tweak" to the main TeX file is tiny, only the package needs to be loaded. Because of deficiencies in the OT1 encoding, the `encap` char `|` is displayed as em dash `—`, therefore I have used T1 font encoding with Latin Modern fonts.

```
%%% test.tex %%%
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{makeidx,showidx,lipsum,indexpagelist}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
John Smith\index{Smith, John}, John Doe\index{Doe, John},
cat\index{animals!cat|(}, dog\index{animals!dog}
\lipsum
John Smith\index{Smith, John}, dog\index{animals!dog|textbf},
Donald E. Knuth\index{Knuth, Donald E.}
\lipsum
cat\index{animals!cat|)}, dog\index{animals!dog},
Donald E. Knuth\index{Knuth, Donald E.}
\newpage
\printindex
\end{document}
```

The raw index file `test.idx`:

```
\indexentry{Smith, John}{1}
\indexentry{Doe, John}{1}
\indexentry{animals!cat|(}{1}
\indexentry{animals!dog}{1}
\indexentry{Smith, John}{2}
\indexentry{animals!dog|textbf}{2}
\indexentry{Knuth, Donald E.}{2}
\indexentry{animals!cat|)}{3}
\indexentry{animals!dog}{3}
\indexentry{Knuth, Donald E.}{3}
```

The main index file is generated as usual:

```
$ makeindex test
```

The index file `test.ind` for `\printindex`:

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item animals
    \subitem cat, 1--3
    \subitem dog, 1, \textbf{2}, 3

  \indexspace

  \item Doe, John, 1

  \indexspace

  \item Knuth, Donald E., 2, 3

  \indexspace

  \item Smith, John, 1, 2

\end{theindex}
```

The file with the page list mappings is generated by:

```
$ makeindex -s indexpagelist.ist -t test-ipl.ilg -o test.ipl test.idx
```

For convenience I have added both calls of makeindex via `\immediate\write18` in the package file (TeX Live executes them with restricted shell escape).

The file `test.ipl` contains the mappings from the index keys to their page lists:

```
iplItemA{animals}
\iplItemB{cat}
\iplPageList{1\iplMultiPage--3}
\iplItemB{dog}
\iplPageList{1\iplMultiPage, \textbf{2}\iplMultiPage, 3}
\iplItemA{Doe, John}
\iplPageList{1}
\iplItemA{Knuth, Donald E.}
\iplPageList{2\iplMultiPage, 3}
\iplItemA{Smith, John}
\iplPageList{1\iplMultiPage, 2}
```

That defines macros such as `\ipl@animals!dog` with contents `1, \textbf{2}, 3`.
Macro `\iplMultiPage` is used as marker to detect single and multi page lists more easily.

Then the package hooks into `\@showidx` to add the page list.

The index:

> [image: index]

Page 1:

> [image: page 1]

Page 2:

> [image: page 2]

Page 3:

> [image: page 3]

Comment: Wow - great! OK, it's not a small tweak ;)
Your listing of indexpagelist.sty seems slightly faulty: in line 28 I'm missing 'me}' (maybe too long line?). Having fixed that, it works. Thank you!
Any idea on how to enforce that it always appears on the right margin even with twosided (that's my tufte-book problem...)?

Comment: @PiscoSour: Thanks, I fixed the truncated line, it was indeed a copy and paste error.

Comment: @PiscoSour: Quick and dirty: `\usepackage{showidx} \makeatletter\let\@leftidx\@rightidx\makeatother`.

Comment: Wow! Did you just come up with indexpagelist to solve this question, or was it something you already had lying around?  I've been able to make use of it, but I'm wondering if you have some thoughts on getting it to work with hyperref as it doesn't seem to like \hyperpage{pagenum}.